# Using custom cell outlets inside of method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uislider

I'm trying to change the label (titleOutlet) within my cell using my sliderChanged (slider value changed) method but I don't know how to access the label outlet like we do it cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomisationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CustomisationObject *movie = (localArray)[indexPath.row];

    cell.titleOutlet.text = movie.localChannel;
    cell.sliderOutlet.value = movie.localValue.integerValue;

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {

    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%f", [slider value]);

    CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: When you change your slider value, is the `sliderChanged` method being hit?

Comment: Is the slider in the cell? Then you should be doing the interaction with the slider and the text within your `CustomisationCell`

Comment: If you access an array using only the `indexPath.row`, the solution will only work in a `tableView` with 1 section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the `indexPath` of the cell, you could use:

```
CustomisationCell *cell = (CustomisationCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"%@", cell.titleOutlet.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a tag on the UISlider and set it to the row index so you can get the row you want later.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomisationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CustomisationObject *movie = (localArray)[indexPath.row];

    cell.titleOutlet.text = movie.localChannel;
    cell.sliderOutlet.value = movie.localValue.integerValue;
    cell.sliderOutlet.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {

    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%f", [slider value]);

    NSInterger rowIndex = [sender tag];

    CustomisationCell *cell = (CustomisationCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:rowIndex inSection:0];

    cell.titleOutlet.text = "new text from slider";

}
```

Comment: This solution does not work in a `tableView` with more than 1 section

Comment: ok but his code is for only one section or every section has the same exact data. `CustomisationObject *movie = (localArray)[indexPath.row];`

Comment: It's very possible that each section would have the same information in the row(s) but have differentiating info in the headers. For example, a table with n sections with a "setting type" in the header and a slider/label in the row to adjust that particular setting.

Comment: That would mean that changing one slider would affect all the other ones since your model would be the same for all one them.

Comment: Sorry- I see the point you're making now. You're not talking about `tableView`s in general, but rather the asker's specific code. Since he's already done the heavy lifting to get the `indexPath` in the `sliderChanged` method, it's easier to go ahead and use the `indexPath` in case the table is later changed to incorporate multiple sections.